# Reusing same plugin for both oxygen author and oxygen content fusion

Tags: oxygenxml

Is there a way to reuse the same plugin such as an ‘if’ condition to check

if(Oxygen XML Author){

steps 1 and 2

} else if (Oxygen content Fusion){

steps say 3 and 4

}

What is the format of ‘if’condition to be checked if the plugin is being run in oxygen author or content fusion so I can reuse the same plugin in both the places (Note: we use java 11 to develop the plugin)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.